# rethrowing python exception. Which to catch?

Tags: python, exception, throw, rethrow

I'm learning to use python. I just came across this article:
http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200711/rethrowing_exceptions_in_python.html
It describes rethrowing exceptions in python, like this:

```
try:
    do_something_dangerous()
except:
    do_something_to_apologize()
    raise
```

Since you re-throw the exception, there should be an "outer catch-except" statement. But now, I was thinking, what if the `do_something_to_apologize()` inside the except throws an error. Which one will be caught in the outer "catch-except"? The one you rethrow or the one thrown by `do_something_to_apologize()` ?
Or will the exception with the highest priotiry be caught first?

Comment: The one that happens first.

Comment: The one you were catching ?

Comment: *'Since you re-throw the exception, there shouold [sic] be an "outer catch-except"'* - not necessarily, some errors should get all the way to the user. *'do_something_to_apologize() inside the except throws an error'* - the thing you're doing to recover from errors should generally not be error-prone! Sometimes, of course, it's unavoidable. *'the exception with the highest priotiry [sic]'* - how should errors be prioritised? Most standard errors inherit from `Exception`, there's not much hierarchy. Questions aside, though, **why don't you just try it and see?**

Comment: This is exactly why (a) you want to write exception handlers that either can't raise, or can only raise in specific situations that you understand very well, and (b) you want to actually get the exception object, at least during early debugging, so you can, e.g., `print('do_something_dangerous raised {!r}'.format(e))` at least level and see what's going on.

Comment: Also, notice that in Ned's "real" code he handles only `except Exception`, not just bare `except:`. Partly this is to allow him to capture the exception with `except Exception, e:` (although this is an old blog, so it uses old syntax; you want `except Exception as e:`), and partly to avoid catching things like `KeyboardInterrupt`, which you very rarely want to handle. (When you do, make it explicit with `except BaseException:`. That wasn't an option in older Python, but assuming you're writing for, e.g., 2.6 or 3.0, it is.)

Comment: Well I've got following situation. I have to copy from one usb drive to another. At the destination I have to create a folder, where I can copy to. If something goes wrong during the copy process, I want to remove the destination folder if something goes wrong, so I don't have a incomplete destination folder. To remove the folder I have to call a function that removes the folder. But that might cause a new exception, I guess :/

Comment: @user2815780: For that case, you probably want to handle the `apologize` code in some way, so you can raise an exception that lets you code/the end user know that you failed and then failed to clean up. (Or maybe create the folder in a temporary location on the destination drive/filesystem so the worst-case scenario isn't as bad and maybe doesn't have to be reported.) But otherwise, yeah, that's a perfectly reasonable use to exception-handling code that may raises.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Try it and see:

```
def failure():
    raise ValueError, "Real error"

def apologize():
    raise TypeError, "Apology error"

try:
    failure()
except ValueError:
    apologize()
    raise
```

The result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#14>", line 10, in <module>
    apologize()
  File "<pyshell#14>", line 5, in apologize
    raise TypeError, "Apology error"
TypeError: Apology error
```

The reason: the "real" error from the original function was already caught by the `except`.  `apologize` raises a new error *before the `raise` is reached*.  Therefore, the `raise` in the `except` clause is never executed, and only the apology's error propagates upward.  If `apologize` raises an error, Python has no way of knowing that you were going to raise a different exception after `apologize`.

Note that in Python 3, the traceback will mention *both* exceptions, with a message explaining how the second one arose:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./prog.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "./prog.py", line 2, in failure
ValueError: Real error

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./prog.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "./prog.py", line 5, in apologize
TypeError: Apology error
```

However, the second exception (the "apology" exception) is still the only one that propagates outward and can be caught by a higher-level `except` clause.  The original exception is mentioned in the traceback but is subsumed in the later one and can no longer be caught.

Comment: is there a way to get the python 3 behaviour in python 2?

Comment: I personally find the python 3 behavior somewhat opinionated in a wrong way (better have let the catcher decide whether to log the exception they captured or not) and also not consistent with catching without re-raising. The python 3 text "During handling" showing between every two exceptions in the chain of exception captures is quite exacerbating on this tangent. The extended syntax from the other answer side-steps this dubious message, while still making you emit a stacktrace hierarchy of exceptions even if you are fine with only the final one that you choose to raise.

Answer (score 8):

The exception thrown by do_something_to_apologize() will be caught. The line containing raise will never run, because of the exception thrown by do_something_to_apologize. Also, I don't believe there is any idea of "priority" in python exceptions.

Comment: Seems the other answer got the most votes, possibly due to its detail and "try it and see" approach (always good), but imho it doesn't actually answer the original question which was "Which one will be caught in the *outer* 'catch-except'? The one you rethrow or the one thrown by do_something_to_apologize() ?"  This answer by ibebrett does answer that question.  The general rule is that once something raises an exception, nothing else can also raise an exception until that first exception is caught: thus if apologize() raises an exception then the raise right after it will never get executed.

Answer (score 4):

I believe a better idea is to use

```
raise NewException("Explain why") from CatchedException
```

pattern. In particular, considering Python 3 and the example given by @BrenBarn I use following

```
def failure():
    raise ValueError("Real error")

try:
    failure()
except ValueError as ex:
    raise TypeError("Apology error") from ex
```

which yields

```
--------- ValueError----                                
Traceback (most recent call last) 
      4 try:
----> 5     failure()
      6 except ValueError as ex:

      1 def failure():
----> 2     raise ValueError("Real error")
      3 

ValueError: Real error

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

-----TypeError-----
Traceback (most recent call last) 
      5     failure()
      6 except ValueError as ex:
----> 7     raise TypeError("Apology error") from ex

TypeError: Apology error
```

Comment: [As documented in the docs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74195316/1509695), and it's probably not elegantly possible to make only the final exception of the chain be raised and shown even if one wanted to (happy to learn otherwise).